# Is Resilient (Constitution) the go-to choice for a level 1 variant human diviner wizard?

Tags: dnd-5e, optimization

I know eventually the wizard will want that feat, but I'm wondering if War Caster or even Lucky (or something else) might be a competitive choice?

Comment: Why do you think your Wizard will want that feat? Can we see your Wizard's stats to get *some* idea of what would be good/bad for him? What do you want him to be able to do, what do you want him to be good at? Right now all we've got is that you think Resilient(Con) is a good feat and you want to know what else is a good feat.

Answer (score 2):

Not even a little bit.

A low level caster will get *significantly* more mileage out of Warcaster than they would proficiency with Con saves.

Here's the most important thing, advantage is much better than proficiency at L1. So giving yourself advantage on concentration saving throws is much better than gaining proficiency in those saves. You *might* want them when proficiency becomes +4 or +5, but maybe not (it sort of depends on the DC you tend to face and how your DM tends to play).

Ultimately, there isn't enough detail to give you a *right* answer, but the one I can give you is that Resilient is *not* generally a good choice over Warcaster.